# xquery- how to get difference between successive values in a list of numeric values

Tags: xpath, xquery, flwor, xpath-3.0, xquery-3.0

I have extracted successfully one value in one variable, and a list of values in another variable (as part of my XQuery expression).

Now, suppose the single-value variable is

```
x=1
```

and the list variable is named y with values
     2,4,7,11,16

I want to extract the following values --
    (2-1), (4-2), (7-4), (11-7), (16-11)

ie, first value of list variable minus single value variable, then differences between successive members of the list variable.

I tried using

```
for $pos in list-variable/position() 
-> if clause for $pos=1 (to subtract and shown list variable- single value variable)    
->else show difference b/w consecutive list variables...
```

but nothing is shown at all as output... What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I. With XQuery 3.0 / Xpath 3.0, use**:

```
let $pVal := 1,
    $vList := (2,4,7,11,16),
    $vList2 := ($pVal, subsequence($vList, 1, count($vList)-1))
 return
    map-pairs(function($m as xs:integer, $n as xs:integer) as xs:integer
                {
                 $m - $n
                },
                $vList,
                $vList2
              )
```

**This produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

---

**II. XQuery 1.0 solution**:

```
let $pVal := 1,
    $vList := (2,4,7,11,16),
    $vList2 := ($pVal, subsequence($vList, 1, count($vList)-1))
 return
    for $i in 1 to count($vList)
     return
        $vList[$i] - $vList2[$i]
```

**again produces the same correct result**:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

**Performance comparison**:

Surprizingly, the XPath  (XQuery) 3.0 query is executed almost twice faster than the XQuery 1.0 one -- when run on BaseX.

Comment: if i also want the min/max value from the resulting list, how do I do that? (In xquery 1 / xquery 3)? Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Your example is so abstract, it is really not clear what you tried to use.

But you can subtract $x or the previous element like this:

```
 let $x := 1, $seq := (2,4,7,11,16)  
 for $temp at $pos in $seq 
 return $seq[$pos] - if ($pos eq 1) then $x else $seq[$pos - 1]
```

Remember to use 'at $pos' if you want the position.

(And btw, XQuery 3 also has the window clause just for this case:

Would probably look like this:

```
 let $x := 1, $seq := (2,4,7,11,16) 
 for sliding window $w in ($x, $seq)
     start at $s when fn:true()
     only end at $e when $e - $s eq 1
 return $w[2] - $w[1]
```

does not appear to be easier, but it is cooler)